# Access .aspx Page Ajax TabContainer in .ascx from .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having the aspx  (GeneratePackage.aspx) which has the Ajax TabContainer for the site. I need to Access the Ajax TabContainer dynamically on the UserControl (.ascx). On Button Click Here is my Code.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page GGG =this.Page.Parent.FindControl("GeneratePackage") as Page;
    var name = (GGG.FindControl("tbcontainer") as TabContainer);
    name.ActiveTabIndex = 1;
}
```

but the it is not access...Can anyone help me to figure out the problem..

Comment: "but the it is not access??" Could you rephrase?

Comment: it gives me error  on var  var name = (GGG.FindControl("tbcontainer") as TabContainer);

Comment: What is the error? Add your error to the question.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in this line  Page GGG =this.Page.Parent.FindControl("GeneratePackage") as Page;

Comment: Use a debugger and check for the value `this.Page.Parent.FindControl("GeneratePackage")`. That would be a good starting point to troubleshoot

Comment: it show me null while cursor move on GGG

Comment: There you go! null cannot be converted as a `Page`. Hence, you the error.

Comment: but sir how can do this any idea..

Comment: Hi sir kindly help me out.

Comment: Recursively iterate till you find a parent that contains the control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
public Control FindControlRecursive(string id, Control parentCtrl)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parentCtrl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.ID == id)
            return ctrl;
        FindControlRecursive(id, ctrl);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
Page GGG = this.Page.Parent.FindControlRecursive("GeneratePackage") as Page;
```

Comment: Hi sir how can implement on btnSave_Click please help

Comment: What is the problem in implementing this in an event handler? Also, how am I know what `btnSave_Click` is supposed to do? Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)